# Failing to build an iOS app built using Cordova / Ionic using Azure DevOps

Tags: ios, cordova, azure-devops, ionic4, visual-studio-cordova

Trying to build an iOS app built using Ionic / Cordova on Azure DevOps

Getting this error:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^5.0.0 
Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@^5.0.0 
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. 
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL. 
Error: Cannot find module 'UNMET/package.json' from '/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.2/work/1/s' 
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I am using a simple setup using the following steps:

- Agent: Hosted macOs
- npm install
- Ionic Command [ionic version: 4.12.0; Cordova Version: default]
- Publish Build Artifacts

[image: Snapshot from Azure DevOps]

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, and the solution was to make sure all NPM dependencies were met.

Check the logs for the `npm install` step and see if there are any unmet dependencies there and add/update missing depedencies in your `package.json` file.